# Circle-shaped Google Map API 3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I know how to make rounded corners using png's - http://search.missouristate.edu/map/mobile/examples/corners.htm

But I want to make something like this - http://www.netflame.pl/map.jpg  and in that case, png would spread all over the map, and it wont work.

Already found a semi-solution, but it works fine only with "iframe" method:
www.netflame.pl/test2.html

when I'm trying to implement it to API method, it looks good only in FF :/
www.netflame.pl/test3.html

Is there any other solution to display circle-shaped map using API3 ?

Thanks in advance!